# Location of httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, apache2, httpd.conf

I have setup a home server on my PC and I can edit my `httpd.conf` file on it.

When I move to my web server I can't see the location of my `httpd.conf` file.  Is it in the `www` directory of the website?

I have checked everywhere on the Internet and I didn't find a good answer for the location of the `httpd.conf` file.  Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, in light of the discussion below, do you have your own "web server"? You won't have access to httpd.conf on a shared server for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Linux, it is in either `/etc/apache2/` or `/etc/local/apache2/`.

For Windows, it is in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache?.?\conf\` where `?.?` is the version number.

Comment: i just need to know the location of httpd.conf file in my website cpanel ..not in my homeserver

Comment: cPanel? I have no clue. But here is the documentation: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WebHome

Comment: i mean the location of httpd.conf file on my webserver ..can it be found on the www directory of the web server

Comment: No. That would be a huge security hole. I do not know cPanel since I do not use it. Otherwise using the file system paths I listed above, you will fine the httpd.conf file and the various virtual site files in /sites-available directory.

Comment: am not telling about just a cpanel case ..i just need to know the location of that file ..

Comment: well is it on the sites-avail directory ??..when i check my public-html folder i havnt find httpd.conf ..

Comment: No. The httpd.conf file configures Apache. The various files under the /sites-available directory configure the specific sites. Your public-html is the web space where your web site content is to reside. Your httpd.conf file is in the directories that I specified before. You can get to them via logging into your system using SSH/Bash and using cd to traverse the file system directories. The Apache documentation is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Comment: yeah i have found a command locate httpd.conf  ..if i connect my server to ssh and type that command will i get the location of httpd.conf file on my webserver ??

Comment: Once you log on using SSH, you can enter cd /etc/apache2/ then ls. You will find the httpd.conf file. Sometimes it is installed in /etc/local/apache2/ so you may need to modify the cd above.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me ..:) ..i will try ssh for finding that on my web server ..:)

Comment: Good luck. Apache can be a bit hard to understand at first, but it is the most flexible and secure web server and in the end, the easiest to understand and configure.

Comment: yes it is .....:) ..

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'proper' location for any config file on a unix system. It can be anywhere the system admin wants to put it.

There are conventions - like putting the base config file in `/etc/` - but they are just that: conventions. It may make sense in some web hosting environments to cather all the config files in each user's folder, or one common folder for the cpanel system.

Fastest way to find out is contact your provider's support desk - it is a common question, they will know.